# Unit testing with storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, storyboard

Is there any way to run a specific scene from a storyboard in the simulator for testing purposes? It's inconvenient to have to tap through multiple pages in your app just to get to the right page you want to test.

Comment: Are you asking about unit testing via xcode/sentestingkit or via ui automation?

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to do it:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UITableViewController *tableVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyTable"];
```

and if you want to simulate the view controller appearing without actually putting it on the screen:

```
[tableVC loadView];
[tableVC viewWillAppear:YES];
[tableVC viewDidAppear:YES];
```

Whether it's actually a good idea to do this is a different matter.

Comment: The Apple docs discourage people from calling loadView directly.

Comment: They do; but this is test code, not production code (KIF is also full of things you should never do in production code). You could access tableVC.view instead (which would cause the view to be loaded), but I could imagine that may end up causing compiler or static analyser warnings as the return value would be unused.

Answer (score 1):

Unit-Tests are rather badly suited for any UI. You should try to reduce unit-tests towards models and bizz-logic, directly.

For testing a UI, aka integration tests, you might want to look at [UIAutomation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html) and/or [KIF](http://corner.squareup.com/2011/07/ios-integration-testing.html).

Comment: Basically, I'm just looking for a way to load a single scene into the simulator instead of the whole storyboard. Maybe that's a bad idea.